# Laravel 8. Eloquent Model Factory(Seeding, db test). How Not to create a model if it already exists?

Tags: php, laravel

For example, I have a user and posts. If the post has already been created. You don't need to create a new post for the second user

```
User::factory()
                ->count(2)
                ->hasPosts(2)
                ->create();
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this, are you testing on a database that already has data? If so would you consider using sqlite for a fresh DB for each test or something like the `DatabaseTransactions` trait to remove your created test data ?

Comment: I think your question needs a little more detail, context mainly!

Comment: Example: 2 users and two posts are created. If the post already exists, you don't need to create a new one. You need to get an id and assign it to the user

Comment: @LewisSmith details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67900485/laravel-8-how-to-do-seeding-with-predefined-data-they-depend-on-each-other